# Dynamic Resizing of UILabel Based on Text Content

Tags: swift, resize, uilabel

Due to some of the data from the API being in the form of long lines and some being short, there is sometimes a significant gap between two labels. I tried the following method to resolve this issue, but it's not working.

```
func adjustLabelHeight(label: UILabel) {
    
    label.numberOfLines = 0 
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping 
    label.sizeToFit() 
    
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
}

func fetchData() {

   DispatchQueue.main.async {

     self.ingredientLabel.text = foodInfo.ingredients.joined(separator: "\n")
     self.methodLabel.text = foodInfo.method.compactMap({ $0.step1 }).joined(separator: "\n")

     self.adjustLabelHeight(label: self.ingredientLabel)
     self.adjustLabelHeight(label: self.methodLabel)

     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                            }
```

Comment: If you have setup your constraints appropriately, label height resizing is automatic. Show us how you've setup your UI